# How can i do this with css? (inheritance of third, fourth level??)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following menu: http://fiddle.jshell.net/KQYsn/1/

Click on link "User" and you will see that a div `funcMenu_content_links` slide down. What I have to do to get the div the same size as the menu? (The div inherit the menu width)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it the full width of the menu, just add a position and left to 0 (so it will start at the far left.

```
.funcMenu_content_links
{
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #C3C3C3;
    height: 90px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
```

If you need it to be the full width of the screen (not just the 4 menu items) then you'll need to set the width to the size of the screen manually. Add the following to your jquery function to get that effect.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#funcMenu > li > .funcMenu_content_links").width($(document).width())
}).resize();
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/KQYsn/7/

Comment: Thank you Tucker, to spent time with my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can give it position: absolute and get that menu width:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#funcMenu > li > .funcMenu_category').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('> .funcMenu_content_links')
        .slideToggle('normal').css('position','absolute').css('width', $('#menu').css('width'));
    });
});​
```

[JSFidde DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/KQYsn/2/)

You will probably need to adjust it some more.

Comment: Almost! I need the full width, to right and to left as well. In your demo the width get full width only to the right.

Comment: I have to go. community, please feel free to delete edit, add content to my very humble answer. Hope they can help you more.

Comment: He probably had to get back to his day job. I don't think he was saying you did anything wrong, he just had to go.